# how to terminate sublime text 3 REPL shell process when using Django

Tags: python, django, shell, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I am learning Django for two days. And I am able to run the first Django project by Mac terminals. But I want sublime text 3 to complete everything, because I have been using Sublime text 3 for two months.

However I got some problem, when I run Django project by sublime text 3->REPL->shell windows.

Problem descriptions are as following:

1,Type Command + Shift + P,

2,run 'SublimeREPL: shell'--running the Mac terminals shell is a little annoying. I want Sublime text to complete everything.

3,Then bash shell window is displayed: I write: python manage.py runserver 8000,

4,And also, the default browser can display desired context in http://127.0.0.1:8000/

5,But, But, But,

there is no use for me to type anything in the sublime text REPL bash shell window.
I can't even kill the server listening process.

The second time I run Django project through Mac terminal shell, it told me:Error: That port is already in use. There is no use even I quit the Sublime text 3 application.

This is my problem.

Still, I find a not beautiful solution:

I opened the Mac Activity Monitor, then killed the a process named 'Python'.

Then everything goes well again.

But, I don't think it is a beautiful solution.
I want a solution within Sublime text 3.

If you have met such problems, and found a beautiful solution, could you tell me that?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try cancel build. Ctrl-C. Shot in the dark. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try Ctrl+Shift+C, it will close the repl and end the server.
I am using ubuntu 14.04 and sublime text 3, and this works for me.